# Theoretical Probability of 3 spinners

Tags: probability, probability-theory

There are 3 spinners that are identical, with 6 different colors of equal size on a spinner. What is the theoretical probability that they:

1. There are no matching colors
2. There are two matching colors
3. All three colors match

I'm currently confused about the 2nd criteria because I'm not sure whether or not I should count the order.

Thanks

Comment: Are the colours repeated across spinners?

Comment: Yep sorry I didn't make that clear

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: I'm stuck on the two matching ones because I'm not sure if order matters.

Comment: Changed the question. Thanks!

Comment: Saw that! :) ... so what do you mean by 'order matters'?

Comment: If spinner 1 is purple and spinner 2 is green, and spinner 3 is purple, there are 2 matching colors.  The order of which two match does not matter.

Comment: This is the same as 3 6 sided dice.  All three die are different.

Comment: So if the order doesn't matter, is the theoretical probability 1/6 * 1/6 for two colors matching?

Comment: What must be true about the third spinner given the first two are matching?

Comment: The 'order' does not matter in so far that a match between spinner 1 and 3 is the same as a match between spinner 3 and 1. But, a match between spinners 1 and 3 is different from a match between spinners 1 and 2. So, whether you explicitly label the spinners or not, there are three ways to get two matching spinners.

Comment: @EricRuochengWu the probability that 2 spinners match (if there were only 2 spinners) would be $1/6$ but since there are 3 spinners that means there's 3 possible ways (1&2 or 2&3 or 1&3) to do it and so you need to account for that. (EDIT: chance of all there matching is $1/6 \times 1/6$)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to compute is to find P(all match) and P(none match) first, and get P(two match) as the complement.

P(all match) $= 1\cdot\frac1 6\cdot \frac 1 6 = \frac 1{36}$

P(none match) $= 1\cdot\frac5 6\cdot \frac 4 6 = \frac {20}{36}$

Thus P(two match) $= 1 - \frac{21}{36} = \frac{15}{36}$

But it is best to confirm by direct computation also.
There are three possible pairs, and we need the pair to match and the third to **not** match, thus Pr $= 3\cdot (1\cdot\frac1 6)\cdot\frac5 6 = \frac{15}{36}$ which confirms our shortcut.